# Bucket policy with Minio

Tags: python, minio

**please note: I am not using AWS as the S3 provider but something called Cegedim S3.**

**Following operation is not working with Minio client but with boto3 it's working.**

When I am trying to setup the following policy with Minio client it works for the bucket level operations but not for object the level operations.

```
 policy = {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Id": "Policy1639139464683",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "s3:ListBucket"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "AWS": [
                            "{user_access_key}"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Sid": "Stmt1639139460416"
                },
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "s3:GetObject",
                        "s3:PutObject"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test/*",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "AWS": [
                            "{user_access_key}"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Sid": "Stmt1639139460415",
                }
            ]
        }
```

Minio connection

```
 def minio(self) -> Minio:
     return Minio(
         endpoint=f"{self.config.s3.host}:{self.config.s3.port}",
         access_key=Secrets.S3_USER.get_value(),
         secret_key=Secrets.S3_PASSWORD.get_value(),
         secure=(self.config.s3.schema != "http"),
        )
```

After setting up this policy I can't perform get/put or any other operation on objects.

is there any workaround for this with Minio client?

Answer (score 1):

If you share the actual error that you get, it would be easier to figure out the problem. However, I would venture to guess that you also need `"s3:GetBucketLocation"` in your bucket level permissions statement in the policy.